# Hex to Ascii conversion in Xquery

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I have a requirement to convert the Hex String to ASCII using xquery, Please help to provide any respective reference or code snippets to achive this functionality.

Appreciate your help..!!!

Comment: Aren't all hex symbols ASCII letters anyway? What kind of mapping between hexadecimal and ASCII are you looking for?

Comment: Please try better. What is “the Hex String”?

Comment: The simplest would be to cast it to `xs:hexBinary` and read the binary as string, but not all xquery processors can do the 2nd step

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decode a hex-encoded string, you can use [`fn:string-to-codepoints($string)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string-to-codepoints) and [`fn:codepoints-to-string($codepoints)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-codepoints-to-string) to deconstruct/reconstruct the strings:

```
declare function local:hex-digit($digit as xs:integer) as xs:integer {
  (: range '0'..'9' :)
  if(48 le $digit and $digit lt 58) then $digit - 48
  (: range 'a'..'f' :)
  else if(97 le $digit and $digit lt 103) then $digit - 87
  (: everything else :)
  else fn:error((), 'Illegal character: ' || $digit)
};

declare function local:hex-to-string($hex as xs:string) as xs:string {
  let $n := fn:string-length($hex)
  let $digits := fn:string-to-codepoints(lower-case($hex))
  return fn:codepoints-to-string(
    for $pos in 1 to $n idiv 2
    let $hi := $digits[2 * $pos - 1],
        $lo := $digits[2 * $pos]
    return 16 * local:hex-digit($hi) + local:hex-digit($lo)
  )
};
```

Then `local:hex-to-string("68656c6c6f20776f726c6421")` returns the string `"hello world!"`.